# I need to show a react material ui confirmation dialog box or a sweet alert confirmation dialog box in handlesubmit function

Tags: reactjs

Im attempting to call a sweet alert in my code which has a login page. Upon successful login i want the sweet alert to pop up. I have added the following code, but it does not seem to popup

// Submit button for login.

```
handleSubmit= (event)=> 
{
   if (token !== null)
   {
        console.log(" ----User Login Success ------");

         return (
              <div>
              <SweetAlert 
               success 
                title="Success !" 
                 onConfirm={() => this.hideAlert()}
                     >
                 Hello world!
                  </SweetAlert>
                  </div>
          );

   }
```

In my handle submit, Once i have verified the user i want to show a success popup using a sweet alert confirmation dialog box to accept the agreement or decline and agreement. But the i cant get the pop up to load

Answer (score 1):

Don't return `JSX` from a function. Instead you can have a state variable like,

```
state = {showAlert: false}
```

And update state on successful login,

```
handleSubmit= (event)=> 
{
   if (token !== null)
   {
      this.setState({showAlert : true})
   }
}
```

Show your alert (keep this in render function only)

```
{
this.state.showAlert && <div>
    <SweetAlert success title="Success !" onConfirm={()=> this.hideAlert()}>
        Hello world!
    </SweetAlert>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add property to state to  control this popup
example 
state={
showToUser:false}
to add action

```
 handleSubmit= (event)=> 
{
   if (token !== null)
   {
      this.setState({showToUser:! this.state}) // if want to hidenn when user click agine it will be hidden


   }
}
```

and add this code to check the state if it is true it will be shown the hello alert else not show anything

```
 {this.state.showToUser&&<div><SweetAlert success title="Success !" onConfirm={()=> this.hideAlert()}>
            Hello world!
        </SweetAlert></div>}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not updating the show property. The best would be:

1. Create a method on Submit which will set the state to show the Alert

```
handleSubmit= (event) => {
  if (token !== null) {
    console.log(" ----User Login Success ------");
    this.setState({
      showAlert: true
    })
  }
}
```

2. Create a method that will close the alert

```
handleCloseAlert = () => {
  this.setState({
    showAlert: false,
  });
};
```

3. In the render where you have the signup button you sould incude the sweet alert. In this example is done with a button

```
render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button
        onClick={this.handleSubmit}
      >
        Submit credential
      </button>
      <SweetAlert
        show={this.StaticRange.showAlert}
        success
        title="Success!"
        onConfirm={this.handleCloseAlert}
      >
        Hello world!
      </SweetAlert>;
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```